# Why does sklearn preprocessing LabelEncoder inverse_transform apply from only one column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn, random-forest

I have a random forest model built with sklearn. The model is built in one file, and I have a second file where I use joblib to load the model and apply it to new data. The data has categorical fields that are converted via sklearn's preprocessing `LabelEncoder.fit_transform`. Once the prediction is made, I am attempting to reverse this conversion with `LabelEncoder.inverse_transform`.

Here is the code:

```
 #transform the categorical rf inputs
 df["method"] = le.fit_transform(df["method"])
 df["vendor"] = le.fit_transform(df["vendor"])
 df["type"] = le.fit_transform(df["type"])
 df["name"] = le.fit_transform(df["name"])
 dups["address"] = le.fit_transform(df["address"])

 #designate inputs for rf model
 inputs = ["amt","vendor","type","name","address","method"]

 #load rf model and run it on new data
 from sklearn.externals import joblib
 rf = joblib.load('rf.pkl')
 predict = rf.predict(df[inputs])

 #reverse LabelEncoder fit_transform
 df["method"] = le.inverse_transform(df["method"])
 df["vendor"] = le.inverse_transform(df["vendor"])
 df["type"] = le.inverse_transform(df["type"])
 df["name"] = le.inverse_transform(df["name"])
 df["address"] = le.inverse_transform(df["address"])

 #convert target to numeric to make it play nice with SQL Server
 predict = pd.to_numeric(predict)

 #add target field to df
 df["prediction"] = predict

 #write results to SQL Server table
 import sqlalchemy
 engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://<username>:<password>@UserDSN")
 df.to_sql('TABLE_NAME', engine, schema='SCHEMANAME', if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

Without the `inverse_transform` piece, the results are as expected: numeric codes in place of categorical values. With the `inverse_transform` piece, the results are odd: the categorical values corresponding to the "address" field are returned for *all* categorical fields.

So if 1600 Pennsylvania Avenue is encoded as the number 1, *all* categorical values encoded as the number 1 (regardless of field) now return 1600 Pennsylvania Avenue. Why is `inverse_transform` picking one column from which to reverse all `fit_transform` codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is an old question, however for everyone who likes convenience:

**apply**, coupled with **lambda** *can* transform multiple/all columns with ease

```
df = df.apply(lambda col: le.fit_transform(col))
```

I despise non-aliased, non-dynamic code (*you should too*) like so, unless really necessary:

```
 df["method"] = le_method.fit_transform(df["method"])
 df["vendor"] = le_vendor.fit_transform(df["vendor"])
 df["type"] = le_type.fit_transform(df["type"])
 df["name"] = le_name.fit_transform(df["name"])
 df["address"] = le_address.fit_transform(df["address"])
```

Answer (score 4):

This is the expected behaviour.

When you call `le.fit_transform()`, the internal parameters (classes learned) of the LabelEncoder are re-initialised. The `le` object is fitted onto the values of the column you supplied.

In the above code, you are using the same object to transform all columns, and the last column you supplied is the `address`. Hence the `le` forgets all info about previous calls to `fit()`  (or `fit_transform()` in this case), and again learns the new data. So when you call `inverse_transform()` on it, it only returns values related to `address`. Hope I'm clear.

To encode all columns, you need to initialize different objects, one for each column. Something like below:

```
 df["method"] = le_method.fit_transform(df["method"])
 df["vendor"] = le_vendor.fit_transform(df["vendor"])
 df["type"] = le_type.fit_transform(df["type"])
 df["name"] = le_name.fit_transform(df["name"])
 df["address"] = le_address.fit_transform(df["address"])
```

and then call `inverse_transform()` on the appropriate encoder.

Comment: that works - thank you! seems a bit bloated though, especially because it has to be included in the test/train file _and_ the predict file. is there any way to cut it down?

Comment: @CameronTaylor Unfortunately, in my opinion there is no tool present in `scikit` to achieve this. Maybe other scientific libraries have it. But it will not be difficult to make one. Just use a dict for holding them.

Comment: @CameronTaylor Also encoding categorical features like you did, is not a good practice.  What you should do is create dummy variables for them. Learn more about the pros and cons of converting categorical to ordered numeric data. Come here if you have any more doubts.

Comment: @CameronTaylor Have a look at https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2015/11/easy-methods-deal-categorical-variables-predictive-modeling/

Comment: thank you, Vivek - I greatly appreciate it. I will take a look at that article the next time I have a moment to go back to this model. sorry I don't have the reputation to vote for your answer!