# Decode pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, decode

i have a encoded dataframe. I encode it with the labelEncoder from scitkit-learn, create a machine learning model and done some predictions. But now i cannot decode the values in the pandas dataframe for the outputs. I tried it several times with inverse_transform from the doc but still i get everytime errors like

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`
```

Thats what my dataframe look like:

```
    0   147 14931   9   0   0   1   0   0   0   4   ... 0   0   242 677 0   94  192 27  169 20
    1   146 14955   15  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   1   63  42  0   94  192 27  169 20
    2   145 15161   25  1   0   0   0   1   0   5   ... 0   0   242 677 0   94  192 27  169 20
```

Thats the code how i encode it if it is necessary:

```
labelEncoder = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
for col in b.columns:
    b[col] = labelEncoder.fit_transform(b[col])
```

The column names are unnecessary. I also tried it with the lambda function, which is shown in another question here but still it doesnt work. What im doing wrong? Thanks for help!

**Edit:**
After Vivek Kumars Code implementation i get the following error:

```
KeyError: 'Predicted_Values'
```

Thats a column i added to the dataframe just to represent the predicted values.
I do that in the following way:

```
b = pd.concat([X_test, y_test], axis=1)  # features and actual predicted values
b['Predicted_Values'] = y_predict
```

Thats how i drop the column from the dataframe that will be on the y-axis and choose fit the estimator:

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X = b.drop(['Activity_Profile'],axis=1)
y = b['Activity_Profile']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, test_size = 0.3, random_state=0)
model = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
model = model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: LabeEncoder is used to encode a single column (mostly strings) to integer. Try inverse_transform only on that column, and not whole DF. Also the code by which you encoded the data would help.

Comment: Just added it :)

Comment: Thats a mistake you did there. Every call to `fit()` or `fit_transform()` will only remember that column info and forget all previous transformations. So now using that encoder you can only decode the last column of the dataframe, not all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at my answer here to know the proper usage of LabelEncoder for multiple columns:-

[Why does sklearn preprocessing LabelEncoder inverse_transform apply from only one column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43128020/why-does-sklearn-preprocessing-labelencoder-inverse-transform-apply-from-only-on/43132019#43132019)

The explanation is that LabelEncoder only supports single dimension as input. So for each column, you need to have a different labelEncoder object which can then be used to inverse transform that particular column only.

You can use a dictionary of labelencoder objects for convertig multiple columns. Something like this:

```
labelencoder_dict = {}
for col in b.columns:
    labelEncoder = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
    b[col] = labelEncoder.fit_transform(b[col])
    labelencoder_dict[col]=labelEncoder
```

While decoding, you can just use:

```
for col in b.columns:
    b[col] = labelencoder_dict[col].inverse_transform(b[col])
```

Update:-

Now that you have added the column which you are using as `y`, here's how you can decode it (assuming you have added the 'Predicted_Values' column to the dataframe):

```
for col in b.columns:
    # Skip the predicted column here
    if col != 'Predicted_valu‌​es':
        b[col] = labelencoder_dict[col].inverse_transform(b[col])

# Use the original `y (Activity_Profile)` encoder on predicted data
b['Predicted_valu‌​es'] = labelencoder_dict['Activity_Profile'].inverse_transfo‌​rm(
                                                      b['Predicted_valu‌​es'])
```

Comment: First thanks for the answer. But now i get the Error: TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str' . That confuse me now :D

Comment: @sataide Please edit the question to include the full-stack trace of error and the code which is throwing it. If you add some original data which is causing this error, that would help.

Comment: Well i added a column where the predicted values are in. Its strange because now the error is a KeyError on the column. I will edit it.

Comment: Does it matter if i add just a copy of the predicted values to dataframe? I mean the values are still encoded.

Comment: @sataide Yes, because in our label encoder dictionary, there is no key with `'Predicted_Values'`. Just skip that key when decoding.

Comment: Yes it works. Can you say how i can decode the predicted values and add them to the original dataframe? I mean i need to decode two times, first the original dataframe and then the predicted values.

Comment: @sataide Predicted values are not decoded. They will depend on what you sent to `fit()` method of estimator (not labelencoder). Did the above dataframe contained actual values ? If yes, then use `labelencoder_dict[actual_values_column_here].inverse_transform(b['Predicted_values'])`

Comment: Yes, mainly categorical data like IDs and some options.

Comment: @sataide Please provide all column names and how you are sending that to `fit()` of estimator. Mainly the column in `b` which acts as `y`.

Comment: I edited the code. I cannot provide the column names because that data from a company so i will choose just some names. But you can see which column a drop from the dataframe that will be work as the y-axis. And i dont get what you mean with 'How im sending the that to fit()?' Im using now your code or do i understand something wrong?

Comment: @sataide I have edited the code to correctly do it now without the KeyError.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you really much. That was i search for.

Comment: @sataide That syntax error was due to some unseen characters from copy pasting in the `inverse_transform` written there, else it runs perfectly

Comment: Yes i notice that. Again thank you very much! Have a nice weekend! You saved mine :D